# Homogeneous second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do you have some hint to solve the differential equation
$$
(x^2 + a) y'' + 2 x y' + b x^2 y=0,
$$
where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x >0$?

Comment: You can try to find a series solution using standard methods.

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to the Bessel equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Answer (score 2):

Maple finds the solutions in terms of the [HeunC](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC) function:

$$ y \left( x \right) ={c_1}\,{\it HeunC} \left( 0,-\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{ab}{4},\frac14,-{\frac {{x}^{2}}{a}} \right) +{c_2}\,{\it HeunC} \left( 0,\frac{1}{2}
,0,-\frac{ab}{4},\frac{1}{4},-{\frac {{x}^{2}}{a}} \right) x$$

Moreover, it does not seem to know of any simplifications of this in terms of more common special functions (which doesn't necessarily mean there aren't any: the Heun functions are rather complicated beasts).